# How to calculate the number of occurrences and assign them to the appropriate place?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've got an array of times in epoch like below:

`const times = [1653931370, 1653924170, 1653920570, 1653913370, 1653913370, 1653902570]`

all of this dates is from one single day between 00:00 and 23:59. Right now i need to assign each of these times to a specific hour along with the number of occurrences of that hour. My response should be like below:

```
[
    {
        hour: 0, //00:00
        occurs: 4
    },
    {
        hour: 1, //01:00
        occurs: 4
    },

    ...

    {
        hour: 22, //22:00
        occurs: 17
    },
    {
        hour: 23, //23:00
        occurs: 12
    },
]
```

can someone help me with this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What should we help with? Did you run into a problem when you tried? Hint: How many milliseconds fit in an hour? How can you calculate the number of hours if you have a number of milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Map over the array and get the hours using the [Date.prototype.getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) method.
2. Then group the hours using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const times = [
  1653931370, 1653924170, 1653920570, 1653913370, 1653913370, 1653902570,
];

const res = Object.values(
  times
    .map((t) => new Date(t * 1000).getHours())
    .reduce((r, t) => {
      r[t] ??= { hour: t, occurs: 1 };
      r[t].occurs += 1;
      return r;
    }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Answer (score 0):

Create new object. Loop over all `times`, for example with for each. Use `Date` class like this `new Date(epoch * 1000).getHours()` and store that time. Check if key `your_hour` exists on new object. If it doesn't, push it like `myResult[your_hour] = {hour: your_hour, occurances: 1}`. If it does exist, then add to that object like so `myResult[your_hour].occurances = myResult[your_hour].occurances + 1;`. That's usually the approach I use but there's multiple solutions to this.